# Parent-child sql query with order by and limit

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, limit, parent-child

I have two tables DOCUMENT and ATTRIBUTES like these

- `DOCUMENT(id)`,
- `ATTRIBUTE(name, value, doc_fk)`.

I need to run a query that works like this "abstract query"

```
select top 100 documents
where $state='COMPLETED'
order by $creationDate
```

Where `$state` and `$creationDate` are two attributes.

Note that the limit is on documents, not attributes, and sort and filter are on two different attributes. The final query should return all document attributes, not only the filtered/sorted ones.

I was able to write this with a very complex query and I'm looking for better alternatives. I could post my solution if useful, but I do not want to point you in the, possibly, wrong direction.

It's ok to get a FEW extra documents, like 1000 instead of 100, and filter/sort in memory.
Could be ok for the limit not to be exact, like 74 instead of the required limit 100, but not too far from it.

Extra "soft" requirements:

- the query should work with several databases (oracle, mysql and sqlserver), so weird analytic functions should be avoided unless available on all platforms
- should work with JPA (eclipselink 2.4.0 implementation)

The expected output is something like this

```
DOC_ID   ATTRIBUTE_NAME          VALUE
  123       state              COMPLETED
  123       creationDate       21/11/2012
  123       userid             someone
  456       state              COMPLETED
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the flaws of an EAV design.

Try this.

```
select 
   top 100
   document.* 

from document   
    inner join attribute astate on document.id = astate.doc_fk
          and astate.name='state'
          and astate.value = 'completed'
    inner join attribute acreation on document.id = acreation.doc_fk
            and acreation.name='creationdate'
order by cast(acreation.value as date)
```

But it's only going to get more complicated if you persist with this EAV structure.

(PS. MySQL doesn't use TOP, but LIMIT instead)

Comment: I think this is not extracting all the attributes of the document.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT doc_id, attr_name, attr_val, creationDate FROM 

   (
       SELECT * FROM (
          SELECT 
             doc.id as 'doc_id', attr.name as 'attr_name', null as 'attr_val', attr.value as 'creationDate'  
          FROM 
             ATTRIBUTE attr 
          LEFT JOIN 
             DOCUMENT doc ON attr.doc_fk = doc.id 
          WHERE 
             attr.name='creationDate' 
          ORDER BY creationDate desc;

       ) AS dt1


     UNION ALL


      SELECT * FROM( 
          SELECT 
             doc.id as 'doc_id', attr.name as 'attr_name', attr.value as 'attr_val', null as 'creationDate'  
          FROM 
             ATTRIBUTE attr 
          LEFT JOIN 
             DOCUMENT doc ON attr.doc_fk = doc.id;
      ) as dt2


   ) as dt0 GROUP BY doc_id ORDER by creationDate desc LIMIT 100;
```

Derived table 1 (dt1)  gives you all the date attributes - to enable order your results by document's creation date.
Derived table 2 gives you all the attribute.. all put together by "union all", enables you to group by document, then order by the date of creation.
Hope this is in the right direction.

Comment: I think this is not extracting all the attributes of the document and creationDate is an attribute in the other table, not a column on DOCUMENT.

Comment: I've edited my previous answer.


Derived table 1 (dt1) gives you all the date attributes - to enable order your results by document's creation date. Derived table 2 gives you all the attribute.. all put together by "union all", enables you to group by document, then order by the date of creation.